# Setting playAndRecord category on AVAudioSession causes a route change

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-audio

I have an AVAudioSession that is always recording, and occasionally plays audio. I would like to mix this with the currently playing audio (Apple Music, Spotify), and only duck when I need to play something. In most cases the user will be using headphones (allowBluetoothA2DP).

When I activate the session with playAndRecord, it causes other audio to dropout for a few hundred milliseconds:

```
try! audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: [.allowBluetoothA2DP, .mixWithOthers])
try! audioSession.setActive(true)
```

This seems to be because it causes a route change (`routeChangeNotification`). Is there any way to avoid interrupting the user's audio when the recording begins? I can't even hide the silence with a tone because I can't play the tone until the dropout finishes.

If I could turn on ducking on demand, it might be workable to deal with a single drop-out at the start of recording. Is there a way to change the session's ducking option without re-activating the session (and causing another route change dropout)?

Alternately is there a way to duck other application's audio by hand? This feels very far fetched, and I don't think I have any access to other apps' audio at all, but worth asking.

Comment: So you’re activating and deactivating your session to duck other audio? If you’re only using one category,  I’d say don’t voluntarily deactivate your session ever once you set it, but ducking may require it. Have you tried changing options without deactivating? That dropout sounds kinda large. You’re not using the voice processing audio unit are you?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman I tried activating and deactivating to apply ducking (which does a drop-out every time, both ways). I tried just changing the category options without an activation (which the docs say is legal), but it seems to ignore that for ducking. I'm not currently using the voice processing (though I did try the .voiceChat option, but I'm currently using .default).

Comment: I've tried lots of different combinations, but here's all the current code. I just have a tiny SwiftUI interface to call these. When I hit play() while playing Apple Music, it drops to silence, then places the sound, then ducks the audio for a couple hundred ms, and then drops to silence, and then comes back. https://gist.github.com/rnapier/e953299037989dd768f67dae0465f819

Comment: If not currently possible, try submitting an enhancement request for this using Apple's new developer feedback assistant.

Comment: @RobNapier - I think you might be up a creek. You have several conflicting  requirements for iOS: always recording [even in the background? => never deactivating], not interfering with other audio except for briefly ducking it => [only activate during ducking]. The problem sounds like something could be solved with two  `AVAudioSession`s: one for sfx/ducking and one recording/mixWithOthers. Of course you can't have a 2nd one, except maybe in some kind of extension? Sfx in a UILocalNotification? IDK. Can you relax any of the requirements?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman This whole path has turned out to be pointless. You can't record from a bluetooth headset's microphone using A2DP. The protocol doesn't support it. What I was actually doing, without realizing it, was playing to the headset and recording from the builtin microphone, which is a useless combination for any use case I care about. Switching to HFP trashes the audio so badly, that that's useless too. I'm going to have to solve this problem in firmware and send audio on a data channel (like iAP2). Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: NP! It’s too bad about Bluetooth input, I’ve always wanted a higher quality input only version. Anyway, sounds cool. What’s iAP2?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman iPod Accessory Protocol. It's what you get to use via ExternalAccessory when you build an MFi (Made for iDevice) product. It's a serial protocol, very similar to SPP, that runs over the classic Bluetooth connection. The really frustrating thing is there's no way I know to do this in a standard way. Qualcomm has an aptX protocol that would do it, but Apple doesn't license it because they do everything over a proprietary AirPods-only channel. So all the voice assistants (Google, Siri, Amazon) appear to be solving the same problems each with a separate proprietary solution.